# ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when it should not

Tags: java

Any ideas on why

```
lines = newRemainingLines.size();
```

would throw this exception?

```
lines
```

is an int I am using to store the size of the ArrayList

```
newRemainingLines();
```

I realize this is probably not enough to give a definitive answer, but perhaps an explanation on what to look for would be helpful. I honestly don't see how this code is concurrently modifying this int.

```
int i = 0;
    POLines.clear();
    itemLines.clear();
    lines = newLines.size();
    //POLines should contain only lines not relating to items
    while(!newLines.get(i).equals(ITEMSTART) && i < lines){
        POLines.add(newLines.get(i));
        i++;
    }
    List<String> newRemainingLines = newLines.subList(i + 1, lines);
    newLines.clear();
    i = 0;
    lines = newRemainingLines.size();
    //itemLines should contain lines only relating to items
    while(!newRemainingLines.get(i).equals(POEND) && i < lines){

        itemLines.add(newRemainingLines.get(i));
        i++;
    }
    List<String> finalRemainingLines = newRemainingLines.subList(i + 1, lines);
    i = 0;
    lines = finalRemainingLines.size();
    while(i < lines){

        newLines.add(finalRemainingLines.get(i));
        i++;
    }
    tempOrder = POF.createPurchaseOrder(POLines,itemLines);
    _orders.add(tempOrder);
```

This appears in an if-else statement inside a for-loop with similar segments of code. This is the final one, but only this one throws the exception.

Comment: Please post complete code and please post the correct line from where exception is thrown. `size()` method call will never throw that exception.

Comment: I can assure you that this line is throwing the exception.

Comment: What is type of `newRemainingLines`? *Hint:* It is not `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Andreas Right, sorry, it is simply a List. Is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: @CreasyBear, if would be much simpler if you just put the stack-trace... It would clearly show which method call caused the exception...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1169) 
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1169)
 
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:998)
 
at Commerce.Ledger.addOrders(Ledger.java:116)
 
at Factories.LedgerFactory.createLedger(LedgerFactory.java:49)
 
at midterm.Midterm.main(Midterm.java:73)

Comment: @CreasyBear Don't post stack trace as a comment. Append to question. Anyway, you have your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subList` returns a *view* of the underlying list. It is not a copy.

Quoting [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.
>
> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is *structurally modified* in any way other than via the returned list.

The statement `newLines.clear()` structurally modifies the backing list, so the subsequent call to `newRemainingLines.size()` says **No-Can-Do!**, aka `ConcurrentModificationException`.

To create a copy, use:

```
List<String> finalRemainingLines = new ArrayList<>(newRemainingLines.subList(i + 1, lines));
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I was unaware subList only returned a view.

Comment: The javadoc says so. Even if you don't read all of it, the first 3 words are: *"Returns a view"*. Cannot miss it!